# How to make a zig-zag layout?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-xml, android-drawable

I want to create zig-zag layout same as following attached image:

[image: Zig-Zag]

I tried a lot by creating diagonal lines and arranging them with icon but couldn't make it same.

I implemented diagonal lines with the help of accepted answer from following questions:

1. [Diagonal line across view](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26278084/diagonal-line-across-view)
2. [How rotate line in Android XML?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15237582/how-rotate-line-in-android-xml)

However I'm stuck to arrange lines with icons exactly same as in image.

Comment: Could you provide some code examples or ideas you came up with? It's hard to help if you don't give anything to help with.

Comment: @Michal I edited my question for further info, please have a look.

Comment: create horizontal linear layouts and add circular items to them.. as per the row #, set the gravity of the circular item to left, center,right (eg #1-left, #2-center, #3-right, #4-left and so on..

Comment: @VinayWadhwa din't you see attached image? I have to put diagonal line corresponding to circular icons.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I created this custom [***ZigZagLayout.java***](https://docs.google.com/document/d/1K2KW7iPgfgvZfu4D4MClkAOzw7-2hYqg7wEDwPc-2sk/edit?usp=sharing) file to cater your requirement. You just have to update the package name in the 1st line.
It basically extends `RelativeLayout`, so you can use it in your layout-xmls just like any other `ViewGroup` class. Once you have instantiated this layout, just add child-views to it like it is done for `RelativeLayout` via `addView(View child)`.

Example code snippet with dynamically created view:

```
ZigZagLayout zigZagLayout = (ZigZagLayout) findViewById(R.id.layout_zigzag);
Button btn = new Button(this);
btn.setText("Test Button");
btn.setLayoutParams(new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
zigZagLayout.addView(btn);
```

I've also added few interfaces to this `ZigZagLayout` for your easy interaction like ability to set the connector-line stroke width, visibility, color, margins, etc.

Try it out and let me know if it suffices your requirement. Cheers.

Comment: I implemented your class and it is throwing `NullPointerException` on line : `LayoutParams layoutParams = (LayoutParams) child.getLayoutParams();`

Comment: As we can't get `LayoutParams` for a dynamically created view.

Comment: Actually you can get `LayoutParams` for a dynamically created view. I have added example code snippet to my answer. Please check.

Comment: I fixed that one, anyways thanks, It don't add diagonal lines after every view, can you please check why?

Comment: Can you share the screenshot? By the way, the default line-color is BLACK. If your background is black too then you won't see any lines :) You can change the line color.

Answer (score 0):

If you have layout for each circular item , you may use relative layout to align them, using align_below, align_left with margin, align_right with margin tags.
Please provide further detail, what are the lines connecting them and exactly what all are requirements for UI and functionality.